# $G$ faithfully acting on $S$ with $|G|=81$ and $|S|=9$, then the action is transitive

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

**Q:** If $G$ is a group faithfully acting on $S$ with $|G|=81$ and $|S|=9$. Is the action transitive?.

**Attempt:**
I proved $G$ is isomorphic to a $3$-Sylow subgroup of $S_9$, but I can't prove that it is a transitive subgroup of $S_9$.

Comment: You could simply note that a Sylow $3$-subgroup of $S_9$ is transitive...

Comment: I could have raised the question as follows "why all 3-sylows of S_9 are transitive?" but I preferred to put the original question. Thank you anyway.

Comment: In fact, it follows easily from the orbit-stabiliser lemma that, if a transitive permutation group has degree a power of a prime $p$, then its Sylow $p$-subgroup is transitive.

In particular, the Sylow $p$-subgroup of $S_n$ is transitive if and only if $n$ is a power of $p$.

Perhaps you could try proving this more general statement. It's instructive and, as I said, quite easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the action is not transitive, let $x\in S$ the cardinal of $Orb_x$ the orbit of $x$ is $1$ or 3. Since its the cardinal of $G$ divided by the cardinal of the stabilizer of $x$. We can write $S$ has union of its orbits. There is at most three non trivial orbits of cardinal $3$. This implies that $G$ embeds in a subgroup of $S_3\times S_3\times S_3$ since $81$ does not divide $6^3$, it is impossible,